# Using a dict comprehension transform dataframe columns into dict

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I've got this DataFrame:

| country | city |
| --- | --- |
| Argentina | Buenos Aires |
| Bangladesh | Dhaka |
| Brasil | Sao Paulo, Rio de Janeiro |

I would like to get a dictionary using a dict comprehension:

```
{Argentina:[Buenos Aires], Bangladesh:[Dhaka], Brasil:[Sao Paulo, Rio de Janeiro]}

x = {k : column.values() for k, column in df.to_dict().items() }
```

It is an exercise and I can only use dict comprehension. I was trying to do the above code, but the result is not what I'm looking for.

Any help will be appreciate.

Comment: Please check [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a trick to split and clean the values lists.

```
new_dict = {row['country']:list(map(lambda x: x.strip(), row['city'].split(','))) for _, row in df.iterrows()}
```